# Manage server-side authentication from Android client

Tags: android, authentication, express, oauth, passport.js

I have set up third party OAuth authentication on my Node.js server using passport.js.

It works well from browser. The flow is the following:

1. Get request to `myserver.com/auth/instagram`
2. Passport redirects me to instagram website to login
3. I type my credentials
4. I am redirected to the callback url, which is my `server.com/auth/instagram/callback`
5. I do further processing and finally `res.send(myAccessToken)` to the client.

I am having troubles implementing this in Android. To type third-party credential, a browser page will be needed. But then how am I going to get the final result in my app?

**Option 1**

Start the browser.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://myserver.com/auth/instagram"));
startActivity(i);
```

Issues:

- I cannot easily set proper headers needed for my server.
- I cannot programmatically read the final response! The action is given to the browser app, which goes to the end and will never notify my app. The user is shown a blank page with `myAccessToken` printed.

**Option 2**

Connect using some http library.

```
final Request request = createRequest()
        .url("https://myserver.com/auth/instagram")
        .get()
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Issues:

- Does not work! Even if I set okhttp to follow redirects, I get a `200` response pointing to some instagram url. Of course the user is never prompted his instagram credentials, because no browser ever opened.

How to deal with this?

*Notes:*

- *I have used instagram as an example, the third party service is not relevant to the question. I am looking for a general solution to receive the result callback in my Android app.*
- *I am not willing to implement client-side auth. I am willing to trigger steps 1.-5. from my Android app and receive the final result in a Java callback.*

Comment: An option would be to do 1-3 in browser, then intercept the 4 redirect using an intent filter and make the last request from OkHttp. Seems way too complicated, I’m not sure it’s possible and I’m pretty sure it’s not the standard way to deal with this.

Comment: ^ looks like it’s possible, but not very good. When we intercept number 4, user is prompted to choose which app should open that url. If he chooses our app, it’s fine, we can go on by internal http client. But if he chooses to keep using the browser, what do we do?